# Group query based on a continuous event in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table of pressure measurements over the time.
I need to create a query that creates an historic of the times pressure measures were below a predefined value, with start time, end time and avg of the pressure during the interval.

```
|          TEMPO          | PRESSAO |
|:-----------------------:|:-------:|
| 1900-01-01 16:26:01.000 |   14.1  |
| 1900-01-01 16:27:05.000 |   14.3  |
| 1900-01-01 16:28:09.000 |   14.5  |
| 1900-01-01 16:29:13.000 |   14.7  |
| 1900-01-01 16:30:17.000 |   14.9  |
| 1900-01-01 16:31:21.000 |   15.1  |
| 1900-01-01 16:32:25.000 |   15.3  |
| 1900-01-01 16:33:29.000 |   15.5  |
| 1900-01-01 16:34:33.000 |   15.7  |
| 1900-01-01 16:35:37.000 |   15.9  |
| 1900-01-01 16:36:41.000 |   16.1  |
| 1900-01-01 16:37:45.000 |   16.3  |
| 1900-01-01 16:38:49.000 |   16.5  |
| 1900-01-01 16:39:53.000 |   16.7  |
| 1900-01-01 16:40:57.000 |   16.9  |
| 1900-01-01 16:42:01.000 |   17.1  |
| 1900-01-01 16:43:05.000 |   17.3  |
| 1900-01-01 16:44:09.000 |   16.1  |
| 1900-01-01 16:45:13.000 |   16.5  |
| 1900-01-01 16:46:17.000 |    16   |
| 1900-01-01 16:47:21.000 |   15.8  |
| 1900-01-01 16:48:25.000 |   15.6  |
| 1900-01-01 16:49:29.000 |   15.4  |
| 1900-01-01 16:50:33.000 |   15.3  |
| 1900-01-01 16:51:37.000 |   14.8  |
| 1900-01-01 16:52:41.000 |    15   |
| 1900-01-01 16:53:45.000 |   15.3  |
| 1900-01-01 16:54:49.000 |   15.5  |
| 1900-01-01 16:55:53.000 |   15.8  |
| 1900-01-01 16:56:57.000 |    16   |
| 1900-01-01 16:58:01.000 |   16.1  |
```

Every time a pressure value goes down 16.0, it starts an "event occurrence". The period only stops when it hits 16.0 again. Doesn't care about values bigger than 16, I don´t want to use them.

So my resultset should be:

```
| OCCURRENCE |        START        |         END         |    PRESSURE AVG   |
|:----------:|:-------------------:|:-------------------:|:-----------------:|
|      1     | 1900-01-01 16:26:01 | 1900-01-01 16:35:37 | <avg of period 1> |
|      2     | 1900-01-01 16:47:21 | 1900-01-01 16:55:53 | <avg of period 2> |
```

I tried unsuccessfully to get this query working. Even try to use temporary tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum to define the groups.  In this case, the sum of the number of rows with the value at 16 or more.  Then filter and aggregate:

```
select min(time), max(time), avg(pressure)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when pressure >= 16 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where pressure < 16
group by grp;
```